# Composer not working when going from Windows to centOS

Tags: windows, git, laravel, centos, composer-php

I developed a project using Laravel 4, in Windows (GIT)

I've got a server running centOS. So, I cloned the repo to this server. 
Since it's only a 512M server, if I run
    "composer update"
It kills the process, since it's consuming all the memory.
The recommmended action here, is to run
    "composer install"
But I get the following error message:
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for patchwork/utf8 v1.1.17 -> satisfiable by patchwork/utf8[v1.1.17].
- patchwork/utf8 v1.1.17 requires lib-pcre >=7.9 -> the requested linked library pcre has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
Problem 2
- patchwork/utf8 v1.1.17 requires lib-pcre >=7.9 -> the requested linked library pcre has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
- laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev requires patchwork/utf8 1.1.* -> satisfiable by patchwork/utf8[v1.1.17].
- Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev].
```

I fixed this by pulling the repo in a linux based computer, updating composer and repushing it. Then, I wouldn't have problems in the server.

I'd like to know if there's a solution, so that I can keep on developing with Windows. I Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the library `pcre` on your CentOS. This is the message that tells you that:

```
requires lib-pcre >=7.9
```

This is system library, not a Composer library. PCRE is now on 8.*, patchwork requires at least 7.9 and your system must have a prior version.

Take a look at this page to see some info about it: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17932519/dir/centos_other/com/pcre-8.12-1.x86_64.rpm.html.

I'm not a CentOS expert, but I think you might get it updated by doing:

```
yum update
```

Or

```
yum update <package name>
```

And if you don't know the correct name

```
yum list installed
```